# LANケーブルをつけなおすと一部のサイトにしかつながらなくなった

Tags: windows

前提・実現したいこと
ブロードバンドルータからルーターにつながるLANケーブルと、ブロードバンドルータからPCにつながるLANケーブルを変えました。
すると、一部のサイトにしかつながらなくなってしまいました。
どうすればネットに繋がるでしょうか？

↓具体的な状況↓

<ケーブルを変える目的>
回線速度を上げるため

<使っている機器>
モデム→NTT
ブロードバンドルータ→WBC V130　(NTT)
ルーター→バッファロー
変えたLANケーブル→https://www.elecom.co.jp/products/LD-GF2BU2.html

<接続状況>
モデム＝ブロードバンドルーター＝WiFiルーター＝WiFiでPCに
モデム＝ブロードバンドルーター＝有線LANケーブルでPCに
(モデム,ブロードバンドルーターは別々に書いていますが同機器)

<状況>
有線LANで接続しているPC→繋がるサイトとつながらないサイトができてしまった。(ブラウザのキャッシュは無関係)
WIFIで接続しているPC→ネット接続無し/セキュリティ保護あり　ネットは全く使えない

<変えた手順>
①ルーターとモデムの電源を切る(コードを抜く)
②"ブロードバンドルータ⇔PC"の有線LAN "ブロードバンドルータ⇔ルーター"の有線LAN　を抜き、上記のケーブルに変える。
③15分ほど待つ
④両方の機器の電源を入れる
⑤上の<状況>になる
⑥上記の手順の逆を試す(元のケーブルに戻す)
⑥WiFiは正常になったが有線接続のPCは変化なし
⑥とりあえず　ブロードバンドルータ⇔PC のLANケーブルを替える
⑨やはり有線のPCが<状況>と同じ状態に
⑩ここで新しいPCにしか、WiFiの5GHzが表示されていないことに気づく

ーーー今この状態ですーーー

回答お願いいたします。

Comment: 困っていることはわかるのですが、状況の把握と解決には手取り足取りのやりとりが必要になりそうで、このサイトには向かなそうな質問です。

Answer (score 1):

一部のサイトのみにしかアクセスできないのは、 [IPv6](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) しか使えない状況になっているからだと思います。 LAN ケーブルに問題があるとは考えにくいので、ルーターやモデムの電源を切ったときなどに設定が変わってしまった可能性が高いと思います。